# C# - Conversion while calling method with output parameter

Tags: c#

Disclaimer: Not a professional developer

We're using SSIS to pull messages RabbitMQ, and I've managed to build a C# script component that pulls and pops messages off our queue for us using `Queue.Dequeue()`. So far, so good. However, we want to have some form of automatic check in place so our SSIS component won't be running continuously, but rather can be scheduled to run every n minutes.

I found the `Dequeue(int timeout, out object result)` method for this, and have managed to implement it like so: (we'd like the BasiocDeliverEventArgs result in order to process the body of the message)

```
object message;
myConsumer.Queue.Dequeue(millisecondsTimeout: 500, result:out message);
BasicDeliverEventArgs ea = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)message;
```

This seems to work, but somehow feel somewhat redundant to me. This, for example, seems more intuitive to me:

```
myConsumer.Queue.Dequeue(millisecondsTimeout: 500
     , result:out (BasicDeliverEventArgs)message)
```

But that yields an error specifying invalid arguments. Could someone please explain why it would throw that error, and why that syntax is invalid?

Comment: Because the C# language specification says so.

Comment: Wouldn't a typed queue be more helpful?

Comment: @PatrickHofman What is a typed queue? Just googled for it, but I didn't immediately see anyhting that'd explain more. As for the earlier comment, fair enough. I was hoping to find an explanation why it would say so .

Comment: `Queue<T>`. Look into generics.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Thanks, will give it a go. I'm always hoping to learn more in order to become a better coder (hence the question, too. I have a working solution, but knowing why something works (or not) is always handy :) )

Comment: @PatrickHofman So I think we cannot used typed queues, because the messages we consume are raised by a different application, and broadcast (by means of RabbitMQ) to subscribers. We (the data warehouse team) simple are one of the subscribers, and periodically read out the messages that have queued since the last time we pulled.

Comment: @SchmitzIT since you are interested in learning, see this [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m4RNTa) I put together which will explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Dequeue` method accepts `object` type in the 2nd parameter. But you are passing it a `BasicDeliverEventArgs` type. That is why you are getting the error. What if there are `Employee`, or `SomeotherType` in the queue, the method will not be able to assign it to the `BasicDeliverEventArgs` reference.

The owness is on the caller to convert it after the method has returned.

Also read this quote from MSDN:

> The out keyword causes arguments to be passed by reference. It is like the ref keyword, except that ref requires that the variable be initialized before it is passed. To use an out parameter, both the method definition and the calling method must explicitly use the out keyword

In c# nearly everything inherits `object` so the method you have called can store any type in an `object` reference (so long as they inherit object) and return it to you. However it CANNOT store any type in `BasicDeliverEventArgs` reference and that's why it is not allowing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this:

```
myConsumer.Queue.Dequeue(millisecondsTimeout: 500
 , result:out (BasicDeliverEventArgs)message)
```

because the `Dequeue` method is allowed to assign *any* `object` to the `message` parameter - it could be a `"string"`, etc - which would lead to VeryBadThings™.

So no: you can't do that.

Comment: Does `VeryBadThings™` stand for something?^^

Comment: Still, the compiler could theoretically give Dequeue() its `object` and convert it to the callers parameter after/during the method. That would be a big mess with scopes etc.

Comment: @HenkHolterman it would also be a lot of mess for the under-the-covers implementation of `ref` etc - has consequences in more nuanced scenarios